Matching names in two columns to return a value in the third column
I have 3 columns:
Column A is account names
Column B are numerical values associated with the account names in Column A
Column C is another list of account names.
I am trying to see that if any account name in column A matches any account name in column C then return the numerical value in column B that is associated with that account name in column A
example:
Account Names     15      Account Names     "value from B if any of the names in column a and C match"
I have tried Vlookup and If statements sadly my knowledge does not go much beyond this.

What was the VLOOKUP you tried.  It should work

Try XLOOKUP() or INDEX(MATCH()) .

This is what I tried.  =VLOOKUP(C2,A:A,2,FALSE)

=VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,FALSE)

Is there another option instead of "true" or "false"  let's say one column says Global Payments and the other says Global Payments Inc.

First-hit
For the first such match:
=INDEX(C4:C10,MATCH(E4:E10,B4:B10,0))



Every hit
To return repective values for every such match:
=BYROW(E4:E10,LAMBDA(a_,TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTER(C4:C10,--ISNUMBER(MATCH(B4:B10,a_,0))))))


function for this scenario specifically assumes Office 365 compatible version Excel
